# Sum the values of certain rows to another nearest row based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe as below

```
id  log loc     pos_evnts   neg_evnts   As  non_As  pos_wrds    neg_wrds    As/Ac
A   c   City    8           0           48  0       0           0           1
A   d   City    2           6           0   180     4           10          0
A   e   City    0           22          87  0       0           0           1
A   f   City    8           0           35  0       0           0           1
A   g   City    8           2           42  0       0           0           1
A   h   City    4           4           0   115     4           2           0
A   i   City    2           0           32  0       0           0           1
B   j   Hill    3           0           24  0       0           0           1
B   k   City    6           8           116 0       0           2           1
B   l   City    2           4           200 0       0           2           1
C   m   City    2           0           40  0       0           0           0
C   n   Hill    5           0           1   0       2           0           0
C   o   City    5           0           7   0       0           5           1
```

As you can see, there are zeroes(0) in the column `As/Ac`.
What i want to do is, when we have a zero, add the values of the zeros rows to the next 1 row. The result expected is as either of the one below.

Here values of the 'zero' rows added to the closet 1 row below it but the 'zero' row itself has not changed.

```
id  log loc     pos_evnts   neg_evnts   As  non_As  pos_wrds    neg_wrds    As/Ac
A   c   City    8           0           48  0       0           0           1
A   d   City    2           6           0   180     4           10          0
A   e   City    2           28          87  180     4           10          1
A   f   City    8           0           35  0       0           0           1
A   g   City    8           2           42  0       0           0           1
A   h   City    4           4           0   115     4           2           0
A   i   City    6           4           32  115     4           2           1
B   j   Hill    3           0           24  0       0           0           1
B   k   City    6           8           116 0       0           2           1
B   l   City    2           4           200 0       0           2           1
C   m   City    2           0           40  0       0           0           0
C   n   Hill    5           0           1   0       2           0           0
C   o   City    12          0           48  0       5           5           1
```

or

Here values of the 'zero' rows added to the closet 1 row below & also the 'zero' row itself is updated with new values except for column As/Ac.
I want As/Ac to be unchanged because i will drop the zero rows later.

```
id  log loc     pos_evnts   neg_evnts   As  non_As  pos_wrds    neg_wrds    As/Ac
A   c   City    8           0           48  0       0           0           1
A   d   City    2           28          87  180     4           10          0
A   e   City    2           28          87  180     4           10          1
A   f   City    8           0           35  0       0           0           1
A   g   City    8           2           42  0       0           0           1
A   h   City    6           4           32  115     4           2           0
A   i   City    6           4           32  115     4           2           1
B   j   Hill    3           0           24  0       0           0           1
B   k   City    6           8           116 0       0           2           1
B   l   City    2           4           200 0       0           2           1
C   m   City    12          0           48  0       5           5           0
C   n   Hill    12          0           48  0       5           5           0
C   o   City    12          0           48  0       5           5           1
```

I tried `df['As/Ac'].shift(fill_value=0).shift(-1).cumsum()` which gives the group' where zero's are followed by one's but i am not able to proceed further (summing them) because i need to retain the first 3 columns & they are different.

I also tried as below but i get an error.

```
df['validheads'] = df['As/Ac'].shift(fill_value=0).shift(-1).cumsum()
df.iloc[:,3:].groupby(['validheads'],as_index=False).sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can a reverse cumsum (cumsum after reversing the `As/Ac` column) and the group on that column then use `.agg` to aggregate the values

```
df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'As/Ac'].cumsum()[::-1]).agg({'id': 'last',
                                                      'log': 'last',
                                                      'loc': 'last',
                                                      'pos_evnts':'sum',
                                                      'neg_evnts':'sum',
                                                      'As':'sum',
                                                      'non_As':'sum',
                                                      'pos_wrds':'sum',
                                                      'neg_wrds':'sum',
                                                      'As/Ac': 'last'}).sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output will be

```
    id  log loc     pos_evnts   neg_evnts   As  non_As  pos_wrds    neg_wrds    As/Ac
0   A   c   City    8           0           48  0       0           0           1
1   A   e   City    2           28          87  180     4           10          1
2   A   f   City    8           0           35  0       0           0           1
3   A   g   City    8           2           42  0       0           0           1
4   A   i   City    6           4           32  115     4           2           1
5   B   j   Hill    3           0           24  0       0           0           1
6   B   k   City    6           8           116 0       0           2           1
7   B   l   City    2           4           200 0       0           2           1
8   C   o   City    12          0           48  0       2           5           1
```

Comment: You can actually achieve this easier:  df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'As/Ac'].cumsum()[::-1]).cumsum()    congratulations on the reverse cumsum, i will be using adding that to my knowledgebase :-) You answer will match moys with  df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'As/Ac'].cumsum()[::-1]).cumsum()

Comment: OP want the first three columns also

Comment: I think he'll like this better:  df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'As/Ac'].cumsum()[::-1]).cumsum()  ;-)  i'm going to delete my answer when you add it.

Comment: please add this to your answer, so that other people can refer later

Comment: Thanks Shijith. This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

moys, with some help from jezrael, i finished up my solution, i was missing two lines that i've added below

```
df['Truth'] = df['As/Ac'] == 0 | ( (df['As/Ac'].shift() == 0) & (df['As/Ac'] == 1) ) 
df['T'] = df['Truth'].ne(df['Truth'].shift()).cumsum() 
# from jezrael
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns.difference(['T']) 
df.loc[df['Truth'], cols] = df.loc[df['Truth'], cols] .groupby(df['T']).cumsum()

   id log   loc  pos_evnts  neg_evnts   As  non_As  pos_wrds  neg_wrds  As/Ac  Truth  T
0   A   c  City          8          0   48       0         0         0      1  False  1
1   A   d  City          2          6    0     180         4        10      0   True  2
2   A   e  City          2         28   87     180         4        10      1   True  2
3   A   f  City          8          0   35       0         0         0      1  False  3
4   A   g  City          8          2   42       0         0         0      1  False  3
5   A   h  City          4          4    0     115         4         2      0   True  4
6   A   i  City          6          4   32     115         4         2      1   True  4
7   B   j  Hill          3          0   24       0         0         0      1  False  5
8   B   k  City          6          8  116       0         0         2      1  False  5
9   B   l  City          2          4  200       0         0         2      1  False  5
10  C   m  City          2          0   40       0         0         0      0   True  6
11  C   n  Hill          7          0   41       0         2         0      0   True  6
12  C   o  City         12          0   48       0         2         5      1   True  6
```

Modifying Shijith's answer with his permission you will get:

```
In [4658]: df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'As/Ac'].cumsum()[::-1]).cumsum()                                                                                                                           
Out[4658]: 
    pos_evnts  neg_evnts   As  non_As  pos_wrds  neg_wrds  As/Ac
0           8          0   48       0         0         0      1
1           2          6    0     180         4        10      0
2           2         28   87     180         4        10      1
3           8          0   35       0         0         0      1
4           8          2   42       0         0         0      1
5           4          4    0     115         4         2      0
6           6          4   32     115         4         2      1
7           3          0   24       0         0         0      1
8           6          8  116       0         0         2      1
9           2          4  200       0         0         2      1
10          2          0   40       0         0         0      0
11          7          0   41       0         2         0      0
12         12          0   48       0         2         5      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have up-voted it. However, i am accepting Shijith's answer because i want the first  3 columns (which are text) & with his code the rows with zero(0) in `As/Ac` column are deleted as well (which i wanted to do separately later)

Comment: He deserves the credit. Thank you so much for putting such an interesting question, i live for solving these, i wish there were more like it :-)